# DateFormatSymbols gives the wrong translation of months/days

Tags: java, date, java-11

We've recently migrated from Java 8 to 11. Upon testing our new version we discovered that when a date is spelled out (dddd, dd MMMM yyyy) the resulting months/days are in English. Our default locale is set to nl_NL. Reverting back to Java 8 fixes the problem so it is related to the upgrade. We've tried a number of things:

- Setting default locale tot nl_NL in docker image and application
- Setting "java.locale.providers" to "COMPAT,CLDR"
- Upgrading libraries

When debugging our acceptatie environment, we notice that DateFormatSymbols has the wrong translation of months/weeks.

[image]

EDIT:
The problem occurs when generating Word documents from user created templates. These templates contain mergefields, these mergefields are used to create the correct document. The dateformat is being set on the mergefield (e.g.  { MERGEFIELD Merge_Date @ "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy" }). Library used for generating these documents is Aspose Word. The Aspose library is using the `DateFormatSymbols` for conversion.

Help would be appreciated, we've ran out of idea's.

Comment: Shouldn't `dddd` rather be `EEEE`? I mean what do you expect from a spelled out day of month? When I use this pattern and print out a `new Date()` (today), I get this output: `0027, 27 September 2021`

Comment: I'll add a bit more info

Comment: Thanks, please add some code snippets, too.

Comment: You shouldn’t be using `DateFormatSymbols`. That class belongs with the old and trouble some date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) since Java 1.8. Not that it’s likely in itself to solve your issue.

Comment: It is the Aspose library that is using the DateFormatSymbols for conversion.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my Java 11 with default locale providers I get for example `[januari, februari, maart, april, mei, juni, juli, augustus, september, oktober, november, december, ]`.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("nl-NL"))));` output on your system? I get `maandag 27 september 2021`.

Comment: @OleV.V. the output is Monday, 27 September 2021

Comment: Note that the language tag appears to use a hyphen rather than an underscore.  This may be a factor as the question indicates that you are setting it to `nl_NL` whereas OleV.V. comments indicates he is using `nl-NL`.

Comment: Post brief, but complete, example code demonstrating your problem so we might verify.

Comment: @vsfDawg That’s no issue. The langauge tag is `nl-NL` alright, which you also see in the image in the question. `Locale.toString()` produces `nl_NL` with an underscore for historic reasons, which is shown in the image too.

Comment: @Daan Thanks for answering. That’s weird alright. It could look like your locale data are corrupt or even missing. Does it work with Java 10 or 12, for example?

Comment: After days of debugging we finally traced the issue back to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8261913. Thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried posting the java issue in the answer but it got moderated because it is not an solution to the bug, which is correct. We fixed our problem by removing the flight recorder from our Docker image. As said, setting the flag causes the language providers to be loaded very early in the startup process and when only the default en_US locale is available. Link to the java bug is:

Link: [Flight Recorder VM Option causes wrong initialization of Locale Providers](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8261913) in the JDK Bug System

Comment: That’s right, a link alone does not count as an answer on Stack Overflow, also because links may go stale with time. Your new answer is good, it explains in the answer itself what the fix is and what the problem was.